# running code in two gpus consume more time, when run independently, as compared to running in a single one

Tags: python, performance, gpu, nvidia, onnxruntime

I am trying to inference model with the best possible speed.
While testing, I found that one inference take 34 milliseconds ( on average), when run on one GPU.
And one inference ( on average) take 40 milliseconds, when requested to two GPUs, independently.
And one inference ( on average) take 50 milliseconds, when requested to three GPUs, independently.
And one inference ( on average) take 64milliseconds, when requested to four GPUs, independently.

This inference is performed with different workers, i.e., for 4 GPUs, 4 workers are run, similarly, for n GPUs, n parallel workers are run. And each worker is assigned a specific GPU.

I am using the following code, to measure the time, for each inference

```
st_m = time.time()
output = ort_model.generate( **inputs )
end_time_m = time.time()
```

I am investigating that what could be the possible reasons that the time increases, with the increase in number of parallel inference independently from the GPUs.

Comment: The times you've given suggest the GPUs are running in series, not parallel.

Comment: maybe some bottleneck on data transfer to/from GPU/RAM/CPU? You could try to make tests without sending data (for example generate dummy input on GPU)